# How to create project versions

Tags: git

I have a project that I'm using git to control its versions. Now, I'm going to work on a 2.0 version that will be uploaded to the server after we finish it.
So, I decided to create a new branch to develop the 2.0 version.

My question is: as the master branch is always having bugs fixed, I need to upload this changes to the server without upload the changes related to the version 2.0.

How do you do to make it? The best solution I could find is use `git archive` to extract the master branch without the changes made on the branch version 2.0. This is really the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of your `master` branch as of code for production. There you fix bugs.
And think of your `master_2_0` branch as of branch that will be on production some day. There you develop new cool features.

Now when you did some development in `master_2_0` and fixed some critical issue in `master` you should make a merge. Make sure before merge that you have your local branches `master` and `master_2_0` in actual state

```
git checkout master_2_0 #switch to master_2_0 branch
git merge master # merge branch `master` into master_2_0
```

This is how fixes from `master` will go to `master_2_0`. Sometimes merge conflict may appear if you changes the same parts of the code. You should carefully resolve them.

So doing merge will leave your `master` branch as it is while will keep `master_2_0` branch updated with the fixes from `master`.

You should deploy to production only the `master` branch. It depends on how do you deploy. Usually it's done using `git clone` with specifying branch that you want to checkout (`master` by default).

`git archive` also will work for you, it also allows to specify branch that you want to be archived.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU the branch `master` is the only branch which needs to go live.
So everytime a new bugfix is added to the branch `master`, you need to rebase it into your new branch. This way, you new branch contains already the fixes.

And finally you can upload the changes of `master` by using `git archive` to avoid sending your `.git` as well.